# how to use update/delete posts of Wordpress REST API?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I just downloaded and installed the plugin a few hours ago and read the documents. I tried `wp-json/wp/v2/posts` and it showed me the posts but when I `did wp-json/wp/v2/posts/24/delete`, it just showed the same thing.

Do I have to download another plugin or extensions to use it? Or do I have to add some custom code in the `.php` files?

Comment: I don't know the plugin really well but I would assume that it is using REST so it would be a matter of sending your request with the ```DELETE``` method in the header to delete and ```UPDATE``` or ```PATCH``` to update.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :D ... after reading your comment I tried adding wp-json/wp/v2/posts/24?_method=delete... and it did work!! thanks xD

Comment: @HelpMeDoe, how did you setup authentication?

Comment: @SiddharthThevaril I'm also having trouble with authentication. Had any luck on it?

Comment: Does this mean to update one should add /id?_method=update?